# How to mock provided function without using injection in Cypress tests in Vue3

Tags: unit-testing, cypress, vuejs3, vue-i18n, cypress-component-test-runner

Though I have a working solution using the global object I'd love to avoid injection. Is there a way to use mocking to achieve this?

This is only about the mocking so the code is stripped down to only show this step.

```html
//myComponent.vue
<template>
  <div>{{$t('some.label')}}</div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import {defineComponent} from "vue"
export default defineComponent({
  inject: ['$t'],
  setup(){},
})
</script>
```

This one works.

```js
//test
import myComponent from '../myComponent'
import { createI18n } from 'vue-i18n'
const i18n = createI18n({locale: 'en'})
const t = i18n.global.tm
const globalProvide = {
    global: {
        provide: {
            $t: t
        }
    }
}
mount(myComponent, globalProvide)
```

This one doesen't. this.$t is not a function.

```js
//test
import myComponent from '../myComponent'

mount(myComponent, {
  mocks: {
    $t: (msg) => { msg }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you might've been trying the v1 syntax of Test Utils for `mocks`, but that has [moved in v2](https://test-utils.vuejs.org/migration/#mocks-and-stubs-are-now-in-global).

To mock `$t`, use the [`global.mocks`](https://test-utils.vuejs.org/api/#global-mocks) mounting option:

```js
mount(myComponent, {
  global: {
    mocks: {
      $t: (msg) => { msg }
    }
  }
})
```